# C# WCF method can not be acessed for the client

Tags: c#, wcf, service, singleton

Why can not access this method ? I create a method where this have informations.

Class code:

```
[DataContract]
class CadastroClie
{
    private static CadastroClie instance;

    private CadastroClie() { }

    public static CadastroClie Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new CadastroClie();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int id_empresa { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string nome { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string tipo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string endereco { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string bairro { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string cidade { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string cep { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string uf { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string telefone { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string celular { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string cpfcnpj { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string rg { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string obervacao { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string data { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int hide { get; set; }
}
```

I need to perform a search method and return the class on client.

The method for search:

```
public CadastroClie Busca(int ID, int ID_empresa)
{
    SqlDataReader objReader;
    SqlCommand objcmd = null;


    vsql = "SELECT [ID_CLIENTE], [ID_EMPRESA], [NOME], [TIPO], [ENDERECO], [BAIRRO], [CIDADE], [CEP], [UF], [TELEFONE], [CELULAR], [CPFCNPJ], [RG], [OBSERVACAO] FROM CLIENTE WHERE ID_CLIENTE = @ID_CLIENTE and ID_EMPRESA = @ID_EMPRESA";

    if (this.Conectar())
    {
        try
        {

            objcmd = new SqlCommand(vsql, objCon);
            objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID_CLIENTE", ID));
            objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID_EMPRESA", ID_empresa));
            objReader = objcmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (objReader.Read())
            {
                CadastroClie.Instance.id = objReader.GetInt32(0);
                CadastroClie.Instance.nome = objReader.GetString(2);
                CadastroClie.Instance.tipo = objReader.GetString(3);
                CadastroClie.Instance.endereco = objReader.GetString(4);
                CadastroClie.Instance.bairro = objReader.GetString(5);
                CadastroClie.Instance.cidade = objReader.GetString(6);
                CadastroClie.Instance.cep = objReader.GetString(7);
                CadastroClie.Instance.uf = objReader.GetString(8);
                CadastroClie.Instance.telefone = objReader.GetString(9);
                CadastroClie.Instance.celular = objReader.GetString(10);
                CadastroClie.Instance.cpfcnpj = objReader.GetString(11);
                CadastroClie.Instance.rg = objReader.GetString(12);
                CadastroClie.Instance.obervacao = objReader.GetString(13);

                return CadastroClie.Instance;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            this.Desconectar();
        }
    }

    return CadastroClie.Instance;
}
```

But I can not access it by the client, if i instance the service class,this method is the only one that does not appear.

Comment: Try changing the access modifier of `CadastroClie` class to `public`.

Comment: `Busca` is contained in Service class and is the only method that is not accessible? Comment the code inside it and make it return void. Does it appear?